# How to add authenticated user (principal) information to ChannelHandlerContext (or anywhere else?)

Tags: authentication, netty

In short, I'm doing 2-way SSL and the client certificate is used to identify my end user.  The SSLHandler does a fine job of that, and the SSLHandler knows all about that principal.  How do I share that information with other handlers so they can do their job throughout the channel pipeline?

Here is where my SSLHandler extension finds the user principal...

...

class MySslHandler extends SSLHandler{ ....

```
public void messageReceived(
        ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception{
    logger.info("messageReceived");
    super.messageReceived(ctx, e);
        try{
                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " + getPrincipalCertificate().getSubjectDN().toString());
                        }
                        catch(Throwable t){
                            logger.error("Unable to see principal ", t);
                        }        

}    
/**
 * 
 * @return Return the user certificate of the principal
 * @throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException  if the peer is not yet verified
 */
public X509Certificate getPrincipalCertificate() throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException{
    return getEngine().getSession().getPeerCertificateChain()[0];
}

}
```

I presumably should add information to the ChannelHandlerContext so it's then available for the duration of the SSL Session and to all my other handlers, but I can't figure out how to do that.  Is this the wrong approach?  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to share it between ChannelHandlers you need to use a static ChannelLocal instance. Ths is needed as ChannelHandlerContext is per ChannelHandler.

See http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelLocal.html